# Reporting potential typos on the contents of this community/site resources?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

If I'm going through this community's help links, tours, general disclaimer, etc. and I find a typo in any content I want to know:

1. Where do I report typo issues?
2. What detail should I provide to report a typo?
3. Who corrects these sort of issues once reported (e.g. moderators, do they report elsewhere, etc.)

### [**Example Source Link**](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer)

(On this link I see in the wording it's listed as **"medial"** rather than **"medical"** as if the typer had an issue with the "c" key while typing up the wording. I assume these are supposed to be **"medical"** and not **"medial"** meaning middle.)

**Typo Wording Areas of the General Disclaimer (per below screen shot below and link above)**

- medial advice
- medial provider

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The typos are now fixed. Thanks :)

---

Now to answer your other questions:

1. You have reported them correctly, here on Health Meta.
2. You don't even have to give a screenshot. Just saying what the typos are and what they should be should suffice.
3. The site moderators cannot edit that page of the help center, so we report to someone from the SE staff who can fix it.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the right place and that the moderators are the ones who can fix it. Alternatively you could go via "contact us" link (written in brownish letters near the bottom of the page, just above the list of other SE sites).